# How to switch to a existing, non-Navigation Controller-View programmable?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, switching

I am trying to switch from a View (a totally normal view) to another view (also normal) programmable. Here is my already existing Code:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {


if([_username.text isEqualToString:name] && [_password.text isEqualToString:pw])    {


    DashboardViewController *destinationController = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:YES];

}else   {
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong Username or Password!"
                                                          message:@"Sorry."
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [message show];
        _password.text = nil;
    }
}
```

So, I want to get directed to my `DashboardViewController`. If I try this code, a black, empty View is shown. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have a xib called DashboardViewController.xib or does DashboardViewController create it's own view in loadview ? It seems like maybe you aren't loading a view.

Comment: I am using a storyboard (no nib files). Abdullah Shafique's answer was really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same problem! Here is the solution I used:

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
DashboardViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

`MainStoryboard` should be the name of your storyboard and `id` should be the View Controller ID which you can set in the storyboard.

Comment: IT WORKED!! THANK YOU! You cannot believe how happy I am!! :D

Comment: @KITZNG Are you using [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Comment: Thank you! I already fixed it! Was a really stupid issue.. I just develop for a few weeks :-)